# How to protect methods with Password in .net dll file?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dll, .net-core

I want to create a .net dll file, which will contains few methods.Those methods can only accessible to users by passing the Password to the method.How can we store the Password in dll file?

Comment: What is the goal of this? Most (all?) solutions to this problem are trivially bypassable for anyone since decompilers are readily available.

Comment: When we give the dll to any customer, based on license will give password to the methods.Those methods only they can use it their application.

Comment: If you have corporate customers, you have legal ways to ensure that unauthorized use gets punished. Apart from that, you could use [.NET's licensing mechanism](https://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3074001) for your library instead of using a password. This still leaves the problem of how you ensure that the library does not work if the customer has an invalid license. It's still patchable, so you'd have to get creative in hiding the killswitches in code. But there's no absolute security and someone determined can probably patch the license check from the library in any case.

Comment: The only real way to secure access to your code is to *keep it on machines that you control*. If you're distributing code, people will find ways to break any mechanism you propose (see: games industry vs piracy)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok sir. actually we are giving this dll to our internal customers ..Is there any other way to protect methods in dll file other than purchasing third party software to protect it.?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: No. Not even with 3rd-party software. If you give people your code, then they can patch out any kind of protection, unless, as Damien notes, you keep the code to yourself. (DLLs count as code here, as they can be decompiled.) You can make it harder, or more annoying to do so. You can change schemes on every release. But you cannot _prevent_ it.

Answer (score 1):

Storing tokens like password in DLL  is not a good practice. But still if there's requirement you can do the following.

Create a global variable in your class library and initialize it with your password value. say

```
string pwd="secret_code";
```

Than define an string type parameter to the functions as an argument

inside the function body you can simple check that the password passed by the user at the time of function calling is matching with the global one or not.

if it's matched, then continue execution else break;

```
function demo(string password)
{ 
 if(password==pwd)
 //continue
 //break;
};

demo("secret_code");
```

Ask for any doubts pls.

Comment: We can also use Encryption Technic to store password in encrypted format, ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - you're on a hiding to nothing here. Once you've encrypted your password, where/how do you store the encryption key? Do you not see that you've replaced one problem with... exactly the same problem.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's the additional functionality you can definitely implement . above answer is precise to your problem only. By the way encryption would be really the best option.

Comment: but the only issue while using encryption is how will you maintain the key to decrypt. i totally agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @PraveenKumar if the answer matched with your expected solution to your prpblem pls accept the answer else we are always here for you. Thanks

Comment: @NitinSingh sure sir

Comment: You could create a hash (sha1) to compare.. like `hash(pwd) == known_hash`. But in reality, if you use .NET everyone can use ILDasm, ILSpy or DotPeek to reconstruct the code and remove the check. Or use reflection to alter the method at runtime. You get some more obfuscation from native code but the only way to fully protect code is to host it as a web service with authentication. Everything else is security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having fixed password then you can have a `readonly` property initialized as a hardcoded value in the constructor of the class

Comment: you mean to say like this example  ..for eg.                                                                                             
        private readonly string password;

        public testLibClass()
        {
            password = "1234";
        }

        public int ADD(int a, int b,string pwd)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if (password == pwd)
            {
                result = a + b;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;

            }
            return result;
        }

Comment: Yes, exactly. !!